# Error in Converting SQL Server stored procedure to Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert a SQL Server stored procedure to Mysql as I am migrating an entire database to Mysql

But I am not able to convert a few of the stored procedures which are using XML interaction. I am not a Mysql guy. So could some one please help me out?

Thanks in advance.

My stored procedure in SQL Server looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_MemberToDoList_UpdateForMember]
(
    @xml nvarchar(max),
    @login varchar(255)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @doc int;
    DECLARE @now datetime = GETUTCDATE();

    EXEC [sp_xml_preparedocument] @doc OUTPUT, @xml;

    UPDATE
        [mtdl]
    SET
        [taskCompleteDate] = CASE WHEN [isCompleted] = CONVERT(bit, 1) THEN @now ELSE NULL END,
        [updatedBy] = @login,
        [dateUpdated] = GETUTCDATE()
    FROM
        [MemberToDoList] [mtdl]
    JOIN
        OPENXML (@doc, '/todos/todo') WITH
    (
        [id] int,
        [isCompleted] bit
    ) [x] ON [x].[id] = [mtdl].[memberToDoListId];

    EXEC [sp_xml_removedocument] @doc;
END
```

When I convert to Mysql it looks like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `conversion`.`usp_MemberToDoList_UpdateForMember` (xml longtext,
    login varchar(255))
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_doc int;
    DECLARE v_now datetime(3);
    set v_now = UTC_TIMESTAMP();

    CALL sp_xml_preparedocument(@doc)
    PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt_str;
     EXECUTE stmt;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
      v_doc OUT, xml;

    UPDATE
        mtdl
    SET
        `taskCompleteDate` = CASE WHEN `isCompleted` = CONVERT(1,UNSIGNED) THEN v_now ELSE NULL END
 ,`updatedBy` = @login,
        `dateUpdated` = UTC_TIMESTAMP()
    FROM
        `MemberToDoList` `mtdl`
    JOIN
        ExtractValue(@doc, '/todos/todo') WITH
    (
        `id` int,
        `isCompleted` bit
    ) `x` ON [x].[id] = `mtdl`.`memberToDoListId`;

    SET @stmt_str =  `sxml_removedocument`;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt_str;
    EXECUTE stmt;`enter code here`
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; @doc;
END
```

but keeps me giving error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1

FYI I am using Mysql version 5.6

Comment: you should try to add the `END;` add this

Comment: @KomalJariwala: You have several errors but not just 1. Need more details on `sp_xml_preparedocument` and other parts of your SP.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

your creating nor sql query, if you wants to create the sql procedure you should must add the `delimiter` in the starting and ending in your query. And `;` add the like my query `END;` as query is following as:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE `conversion`.`usp_MemberToDoList_UpdateForMember` (xml longtext,
    login varchar(255))
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_doc int;
    DECLARE v_now datetime(3);
    set v_now = UTC_TIMESTAMP();

    CALL sp_xml_preparedocument(@doc)
    PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt_str;
     EXECUTE stmt;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
      v_doc OUT, xml;

    UPDATE
        mtdl
    SET
        `taskCompleteDate` = CASE WHEN `isCompleted` = CONVERT(1,UNSIGNED) THEN v_now ELSE NULL END
 ,`updatedBy` = @login,
        `dateUpdated` = UTC_TIMESTAMP()
    FROM
        `MemberToDoList` `mtdl`
    JOIN
        ExtractValue(@doc, '/todos/todo') WITH
    (
        `id` int,
        `isCompleted` bit
    ) `x` ON [x].[id] = `mtdl`.`memberToDoListId`;

    SET @stmt_str =  `sxml_removedocument`;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt_str;
    EXECUTE stmt;`enter code here`
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; @doc;
END; //
delimiter ;
```

**http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html**